# html component written in react not showing

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

This code here doesn't show work when viewing in browser.

```
  render() {
    if (this.state.type == "show") {
      var work =  <a className="image" href={this.props.work.path}>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.work.image}}/>
          </a>
          <div className="content">
            <h4>
              <a href={this.props.work.path}>
                {this.state.title}
              </a>
            </h4>
            <div className="meta"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="extra content">
            <span className="left floated">
              <i aria-hidden="true" className="fa fa-eye pv" />
              &nbsp;{this.props.work.impressionist_count}&nbsp;
              <i className="fa fa-users"/>
              &nbsp;{this.props.work.collaborators_count}&nbsp;collaborators
            </span>
            <span className="right floated">
              <div className="i fa fa-pencil-square"></div>
              <span onClick={()=>this._onEdit(this.props.work)}>&nbsp;Edit</span>
              <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.work.delete_link}}/>
            </span>
          </div>
    } else if (this.state.type == "edit") {
            bunch of else codes
    }
    return (
      <div className="ui card" key={`work_${this.props.work.id}`}>
        {work}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

It was originally like this,

```
  render() {
    if (this.state.type == "show") {
      var work = <div className="ui card">
        <a className="image" href={this.props.work.path}>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.work.image}}/>
        </a>
        <div className="content">
          <h4>
            <a href={this.props.work.path}>
              {this.state.title}
            </a>
          </h4>
          <div className="meta"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="extra content">
          <span className="left floated">
            <i aria-hidden="true" className="fa fa-eye pv" />
            &nbsp;{this.props.work.impressionist_count}&nbsp;
            <i className="fa fa-users"/>
            &nbsp;{this.props.work.collaborators_count}&nbsp;collaborators
          </span>
          <span className="right floated">
            <div className="i fa fa-pencil-square"></div>
            <span onClick={()=>this._onEdit(this.props.work)}>&nbsp;Edit</span>
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.work.delete_link}}/>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    } else if (this.state.type == "edit") {
    bunch of else codes
    }
    return (
      <div className="ui cards" key={`work_${this.props.work.id}`}>
        {work}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

So, when I took out the div.ui.card that was wrapping around the variable "work" it stopped working. But I need that div.ui.card to be at the bottom after return to wrap the {work}.

How could I make this work....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react 15 and earlier, you *need* a wrapping element. So if you want to remove the div.ui.card element from the original position, you can only remove the className, not the element itself.

Wrong:

```
var Item = <div>Some Text</div>
           <div>Another div</div>
```

Correct:

```
var Item = <div>
               <div>Some Text</div>
               <div>Another div</div>
           </div>
```

**Or migrate to React 16**